# I can't use MySQL shell to connect root@localhost

Tags: mysql, innodb

I meet some problems in mysql,

OS:centos7

MySQL：mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

MySQL Shell：mysql-shell-8.0.23-1.el7.x86_64

**I can use ( mysql -uroot -p ) to connect mysql,but I can't use mysql shell to connect mysql.**

My root password is right, How to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to allow access to user to connect to your db https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/mysql-how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql

Comment: Did you try without sh? mysql -uroot

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the content of the `mysql.user` table (without the `*_priv` columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem ,I don't have the Permission in root, so I use

```
create user root@"%" identified by '***';  
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 18.04:

```bash
sudo mysqlsh -u root --no-password --socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```